# Can I create my module's tables before I use the Entity API?

Tags: entities

If I want to create a module, can I create the tables first in something like phpMyAdmin and then do the module, or should I always define them first and have the tables created by Drupal?

What if I need a new table later after everything has been built?  And, that new table has keys that need to fit into the other tables already built?

Edit:  https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/update-api/updating-database-schema-andor-data-in-drupal-8

This answers some of it, but am I really unable to use a tool like MySQL Workbench or phpMyAdmin to do this same thing?

Comment: Why would I get a downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Please don't use php my admin. Use the SchemaAPI and Entity API proper. Creating a table in MySQL and not going through these APIs will cause a lot of trouble.

Future updates to schema can be done with update hooks and updating the initial schema definition.